# Static block slider issue

Tags: javascript, static-block, jquery, ce-1.9.2.0, slider

I have a slider on this website: https://sportinngerritsen.nl/ and I'm trying to make it editable for the user through static blocks, but when I do this, it displays the slider like this: http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/.

I noticed that when I add the following HTML that is needed for the slider to the static block:

```
<div id="slider_wrapper">
<div id="slider_wrapper_inner">
    <div id="slider">

        <div id="feature_list">
            <ul id="tabs">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="current">
                        <h1>Bespanmachine nodig</h1>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                        <h1>De badminton collectie</h1>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                        <h1>Tennissnaren</h1>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="output">
                <li style="display: list-item;"><img src="http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/skin/frontend/default/sportinn/afb/catalog/slider/bespanmachines.jpg"></li>
                <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/media/wysiwyg/badminton-home2.jpg"></li>
                <li style="display: none;"><img src="http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/media/wysiwyg/tennissnaren-home5.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It automatically changes it to this after I updated the HTML:

```
<div id="slider_wrapper">
     <div id="slider_wrapper_inner">
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="feature_list">
               <ul id="tabs">
                  <li>
                      <h1>Bespanmachine nodig</h1>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <h1>De badminton collectie</h1>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <h1>Tennissnaren</h1>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <ul id="output">
                  <li style="display: list-item;"><img alt="" src="http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/skin/frontend/default/sportinn/afb/catalog/slider/bespanmachines.jpg" /></li>
                  <li style="display: none;"><img alt="" src="http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/media/wysiwyg/badminton-home2.jpg" /></li>
                  <li style="display: none;"><img alt="" src="http://sportinn.portalserver.nl/media/wysiwyg/tennissnaren-home5.jpg" /></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hence, it removes the `<a href="javascript:;"`. Does anyone know why this works when I paste it in `page.phtml` but doesn't when I use it in a static block? I recently updated from 1.6.2 to 1.9.2.1 and it did work before the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the editor doesn't consider the html as valid and removes the `a` tag.
you can try to paste this after you disable the editor. or you can just use `href="#"`.

Comment: I see, thank you! I didn't know I could disable the editor, but this fixed it. Thanks again!